# Twisted: How to pass parameter implicitly?

Tags: python, twisted

I would like to add security checks to my existing twisted server, but in order to do checks I need information about Request.
It is possible to pass request-object in every function call, but I am looking for solution to pass it as implicit parameter. If twisted was threaded framework I could use thread-local-storage to save this information and access to the data from any function.
The question is how could I provide request-specific context to be accessible from any function call?

Thank you!

Comment: What request object are you talking about?

Comment: _"implicit parameter"_ is a detestable appelation for what is correctly called an **argument**. That's my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Spooky action at a distance is great in physics (woo hoo quantum teleportation).  However, in software, it's terrible.  It's extremely detrimental to the readability of a program.

Twisted Web (you must be talking about a web server, I guess) offers an authentication and authorization systems via [`twisted.web.guard`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/http-auth.html).  The basic idea of this system is that the `Resource` represents the user and the user's permissions.  It can pass this information down to its children if they need it.